# How to run a Tkinter based GUI application using a Launcher, rather than from teminal

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, launcher

I wrote an application to store data in the database using tkinter and python3. I can launch the application using the terminal by running  databaseapp.py

I want to know if it is possible to have a launcher icon. So that i can run the application just by double clicking on the icon. My applcation will run on a debian linux

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/342950/how-to-create-a-desktop-file-to-launch-a-python-script

Answer (score 2):

You can use desktop files.
For your example, do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Database app
Comment=Launch the Database Application
Exec=bash -c "python3 /path/to/database.py"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

Place this file on your desktop. When you click it, you will be prompted if you want to run the file. Click 'Execute' and it should open your app.

Comment: Thanks the approach works when i wrote a test program which is writtern only in one file but when i run a program which imports from other files this approach doesnot work

Comment: If you use other files do ```bash -c "cd directory_where_your_files_are; python3 database.py"```